# get_query_var('paged') always returns empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, pagination

Putting this up after having hit a brick wall for possible solutions.

Have a site with quite a few custom post types and associated custom taxonomies. To help make things easy, I'm using a unified `taxonomy.php` template.

Within that template there are three loops. I would like all of them to run on the first page, after that, just the third loop. I understand how to make that work with `is_paged()` but there's a bigger problem that I just cannot resolve.

In my `$args` I included `$paged` from

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

But `$paged` always returns as 1, now matter what page I am on. If I do a straight

```
    get_query_var('paged')
```

Then nothing is returned, no matter if I am on the first, second, third or etc page.

I've read that you need to reset each loops for this to work, and that's a practice I've always followed.

I won't include the whole page here, as this is a rather long and complex taxonomy. Instead I'll show the base set up of the two loops.

**NOTE:** I can't use `pre_get_posts` for this page as it affects all loops. Each of these loops have separate `posts_per_page` requirements and other aspects that need to be kept separate.

At the top of the template I have

```
    //this present duplication
        $do_not_duplicate = array();

        global $wp_query;
        $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
```

And I set up my loop after my args with

`while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();`

The third loop that I want paged has this code nearby

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;                                 
                $args=array(
                    'posts_per_page' => $total_posts,
                    'post__not_in' => array_merge($do_not_duplicate, $unwanted_post_ids ),
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy'  => $term->taxonomy,
                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                'terms'     => $term->slug,
                                )
                            )
                    );

                // Re-run the query with the new arguments
                query_posts( $args );
```

I have been using `wp_query` rather than `query_posts`, but for my latest attempts that's what I've had there. Would prefer to change it back.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your code in its entirety? It's a tad hard to follow in prose with snippets, seeing the whole thing would make it a lot easier to grasp

Comment: also keep in mind that query_posts will use WP_Query at it's lowest level anyway, so there's no point in using it as a general query tool

Comment: Try using this: `$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` I am not sure about the reason for this but this worked for me once.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Instead of using:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

I had the same issue and it works for me.

Comment: 'page' is just used for a static front page. Otherwise 'paged' is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "paged" parameter in the URL of the page(s) that you are trying to use get_query_var with? As far as I know get_query_var("paged") is explicitly returning the value of the URL param so you need to have a URL like this for it to work:

```
/?paged=7
```

Alternatively you could read the URL param using straight-up PHP:

```
$_GET['paged']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take this straight from the main `$wp_query` variable, you could do a `print_r()`and check for the various arguments you'd need, like paged, posts_per_page etc etc. What information can you see on your template when doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although specifically paginating using AJAX. get_query_var('paged') returned an empty string, so $paged was always setting to "1", and - although the pages were changing - the pagination links always showed "1" as the current page.

To solve my issue, I just grabbed the page value passed through to my functions file ($_POST['page']) by AJAX, called it $pagination_no, then changed the $paged formula to:

```
$paged = ($pagination_no) ? $pagnination_no : 1;
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `page`, not `paged`, on static front page

✅ The solution:

```php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

⭐️ A better syntax (see [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#source)):

```php
$paged = get_query_var('page', 1);
```

Inside the loop you can just use directly the global `$page` value (see [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Inside_the_Loop_variables)):

```php
global $page;
```

If you are on a **[static front page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/#what-is-a-static-front-page)** you have to use the `page` query variable instead of the `paged` one (see [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#examples)).

The global `$page` always returns an integer.

### A better approach:

```php
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
```

This will gracefully fallback no matter where you use the code.

Here an [old reference](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-post-type-pagination-chaining-method--wp-21444) that tries to solve the issue.